# How to send request json string to telegram and receive message by keyboard button only json string?

Tags: c#, json, request, bots, telegram

I am programming in telegram bot , and I am using only JSON string for sending and receiving data from/to telegram server.

For example I want to send JSON this like:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot347803164:AAEg**************KweblvdP25sYIqpeQ/sendmessage?chat_id=*********&text=**testbtn**&replymarkup=[text=test,call_back_data:1,url:http:www.google.com]]
```

but the response after sending my request is only text message:

```
testbtn
```

and does not have button or replykeyboard?!

I want to send JSON request and receive message by key board button.
Help me please.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understood your question completely, can you please try explaining it a bit further with example code and errors?

Answer (score 0):

1.you have some typos in your request: such as "reply_markup", "call_back_data", or even your google url!

2. you can only have one of the "callback_data" or "url" for each of your buttons.
3. the right format of inlinekeyboards are as follow.

   ```
   https://api.telegram.org/bot347803164:AAEg**************KweblvdP25sYIqpeQ/sendmessage?chat_id=*********&text=testbtn&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "text1","callback_data": "cb1"}],[{"text": "text2","callback_data": "cb2"}, {"text": "text3","callback_data": "cb3"}, {"text": "text4","url": "http://www.google.com"}]]}
   ```
4. if you want to send simple keyboards(not inline transparent keyboards) use the below format:

   ```
   https://api.telegram.org/bot347803164:AAEg**************KweblvdP25sYIqpeQ/sendmessage?chat_id=*********&text=testbtn&reply_markup={"keyboard": [[{"text" :"text1"}],[{"text" :"text2"}]]}
   ```